# Как извлечь значение в виде суммы из таблицы mySQL с помощью LUA

Tags: mysql, lua

Помогите отобразить значение "10" как сумму из таблицы mySQL. где D - сумма столбца C

```
RegisterServerEvent('PRIMER:a1')
AddEventHandler('PRIMER:a1', function()
    MySQL.Async.fetchAll('SELECT SUM(С) AS D FROM X', {}, function(results)
        print(results[1])
    end)
end)
```

[image: Таблица]

Comment: ошибка в чем? если сумма не та , то `SUM(A)` замените на `SUM(С)`

Comment: Исправил, но это не работает. При выводе размера массива "print(#results)", результат показывает: "1" - количество строк. Все работает. При выводе "print(results[1])", результат показывает, хаотичные номера: "table: 0000013EB67DEF10". Я не могу понять через какой оператор мне распечатать значение.

Comment: ну все ок, если есть таблица в результате, просто взять из 1 строки результата то поле , которое нужно `AS D` - `print(results[1].D)` или `print(results[1]["D"])`

Comment: Ты мой спаситель! Спасибо огромное! Получилось. Я неделю пытаюсь разобраться, как это должно работать.